# Laravel Multiple Auth::attempt

Tags: laravel, authentication, login-attempts

I have two models in my laravel v5.4 project, user and admin.

In config/auth.php i added admin to guards and providers as below :

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],


'providers' => [

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

Now in AdminController class i want to use Auth::attempt function but by default it uses the users table. I can change defaults in config/auth.php as below and it works but in this case i can not use Auth::attempt for users.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'admin',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

I want to set user as default but use Auth::attempt function for admin with a method like Auth::attempt('admin',[credentials]). How can i use Auth::attempt for Admin model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call the guard directly, like this:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials);
```

Or with the helper:

```
auth()->guard('admin')->attempt($credentials);
```

Or, even shorter with the helper:

```
auth('admin')->attempt($credentials);
```

Comment: If the admin guard driver uses `passport` other than `session`, will this still work? I got 
`Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.`

Comment: @ultrasamad No, because you authenticate with a token instead.

Comment: Oh ok. So what is the workaround if I still want to use auth attempt on that guard?